# How to install packages without any package manager

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I would like to install a package, let's say `openssh-client`, in my distribution. The problem is that none of the package managers I know are installed on it.

```
# sudo apt-get install openssh
sudo: apt-get: command not found
# ipkg update
-sh: ipkg: not found
# opkg
-sh: opkg: not found
# dpkg
-sh: dpkg: not found
# apt-get 
-sh: apt-get: not found
```

The distribution is a minimal one built using BuildRoot. During the system configuration, I specified the package managers I wanted to use but none of them were installed...
How can I install a package from source?

Comment: The only to do this (AFAIK) is to build from source. You will need a copy of the source files of the program you're trying to install. As well as the build tools, i.e., `gcc` if your source is in C or `python` if it's in Python, etc.

Comment: Ok, so a smart action would be to install a package manager from sources. I'll check how to install apt-get

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to learn by building your own system from scratch? If you just want a system, install something with a package manager.

Comment: Haha. Yes. It's an embedded *nix system but do you know what architecture your system is based on? For example, Linux Mint is based on Debian.

Comment: If you know that you can chose to install the appropriate package manager, but like @FaheemMitha has said, why not install a distro w/an included package manager?

Comment: Just build the package. You might also want to Google *slash-package*. Much of the work package-managers do is necessary only to support package-management.

Comment: The system is for an embedded real time application with Raspberry Pi. The hardware architecture is ARM and I've downloaded kernel sources from https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.
@franklin: I need the system to be as small as possible, this one uses 10 Mb of Ram.

Comment: Do you want the system to be as small as possible so that it occupies the least RAM? Or do you want it to be as small as possible so it occupies the least disk space? They're not the same. I could understand forgoing a package manager for the latter but not for the former.

Comment: Both. I told buildroot to install `ipkg` and `opkg` but something went wrong.

Comment: Do you have any experience building packages from source? It is usually scripted - and problems during a build are usually due to unmet dependencies and/or misconfigured environment variables. [*slash-package*](http://cr.yp.to/slashpackage.html) *(and supporting apps)* handles much of that by minimizing dependencies and consolidating the build/install tree. Package-managers typically go the opposite way - complicating the process several fold but also abstracting the work onto a series of scripts and tracked databases.

Comment: No I've never built a package from source. I've checked this link http://cr.yp.to/slashpackage/list.html but I did not find the package I was looking for.

Comment: I'm on this link https://www.pantz.org/software/ssh/installsshoncentos4.html now.

Comment: Allow me to hazard this bit of advice then - start smaller. You might wanna try building a few interesting projects you find browsing github or something before tackling your own distro design. It's kind of a requisite skill for any kind of useful and manageable outcome.

Comment: Try to find out what went wrong during the installation, i.e. why the package manager didn't get installed. You might be missing some other parts as well...